# decimal(18,10) values in SQL Server appear rounded in Access linked table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database with a linked table from SQL Server.

The SQL Server table has the table structure and the values as below

```
Name        |Total  |Esc    |Variance (Data Type decimal (18,10))
================================================
Name        |29     |2      |0.0689655170
```

but if i open the Access linked table it is showing the Variance value rounded to two decimal places

```
Name        |Total  |Esc    |Variance
================================================
Name        |29     |2      |0.07
```

How can I make the Access table look the same as the SQL Server table?

Comment: I just tried to replicate the issue and could not. My Access linked table has a [Variance] column of type Decimal(18,10) just like the actual table in SQL Server. Try deleting and re-creating your linked table in Access to see if that helps.

Comment: Even I created decimal(18,10) in 2008, 2008r2 and 2012 and linked the access 2007 project, all seems good and reflecting the correct details with correct decimal points.

Comment: I have deleted the linked table in Access and recreated , unfortunately the value rounded to two decimal places. Also tried creating a new Access file and tried. Is anything need to change in Access setup?

Comment: Any help from others? still i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with a Decimal(18,10) on SQL2005 with Access 2010 Front End. Linked table rounds/truncates data.

I have found that this occurs with the default sqlsrv32 ODBC driver updating to the sql Native client driver and creating a new ODBC connection to use the sqlncli driver seems to fix the error.

Comment: Curious to know why SQLSrv32 ODBC does not show those decimals ? but my problem solved when I used SQLNCLI driver.